# How can I implement an InApp store into my App?

Tags: java, android, android-inapp-purchase

I want to have an InApp store implemented in my app, but after a lot of research I haven't found how I can code it or how it will work overall. My guess is, that I hide some areas of my App and only will reveal them after someone paid in my store? I am glad for every piece of information abut how to code an InApp store.

Comment: probably you have to properly go through https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html
this explains pretty well how to implement in app purchases.

Comment: Please post questions which are related to any specific programming issue. The scenario you are describing is not apt to being a programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right way. You can create a login screen and if user login and pay you can show him the download button (to download some app). You can upload every app (*.apk) in your server and the user will be able to download it.

Comment: Thank you, and if I just want to show him a new tab or update some variables after the payment, how can I implement that?

Comment: What kind of tabs and variables?